# Editor for Python Code in .NET Application

Tags: c#, python, winforms, ironpython

I have a WinForms application. One of the requirements of the application is running Python scripts. For this, I am using `IronPython`. I can ask the user to save a Python script file and then execute the script from its location.

But it would be much better and easier for the user if I can provide an in-application editor for Python scripts with syntax highlighting and auto-completion.

Notepad++ is very useful for writing Python code. But it is not configurable through my C# code.

`AvalonEdit` is for WPF and my application is WinForms. I have noticed that IronLab does not have auto-completion.

What are my best options to provide a feature like this?

Comment: From what I have seen in recurring research in python editor controls AvalonEdit is your best bet (when looking at open source/free solutions). You could probably embed the WPF control in your Winforms app. Sidenote: I don't see this as off-topic and not even really a duplicate as it asks for WinForms (Iron)Python editor support which I have not come across yet.